# Does play framework support Nested routes like rails?

Tags: playframework, routes, url-routing, playframework-2.0

Rails make It possible to map resources that are logically children of other resources In the URL for example

```
/magazines/:magazine_id/ads/:id show    display a specific ad belonging to a specific magazine
```

Is it possible to do this In Play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. It should look like this in your routes file:

```
GET   /magazines/:magazine_id/ads/:id/show   controllers.MyController.show(magazine_id: Long, id: Long)
```

And in your controller

```
public static Result show(Long magazine_id, Long id) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Play doesn't care if arguments represents some kind of relation or not, it's job for your controller.

Of course it is possible to do that:

```
GET /some/:parent/:child   controllers.Application.getRelated(parent: Long, child: Long)
```

in controller:

```
public static Result getRelated(Long parent, Long child) {
    return ok(SomeFinder(parent,child));
}
```